# how to get the coordinates of a transformed shape in javafx2?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have 2 ellipses on a pane, one has a rotation transformation applied to it (the rotation point not being the ellipse itself obviously :)), the other doesn't. Now I need to draw a line from the center of the transformed ellipse to the center of the untransformed ellipse.
So I need the coordinates of the transformed ellipse, is there a way to retrieve those? 
(I need them for other calculations besides the line drawing too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `localToParent` method. Example:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle(VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
        Group root = new Group();

        // ellypsis with center in 100,100
        Arc ellypsis = ArcBuilder.create().centerX(100).centerY(100).length(360).radiusX(100).radiusY(50).fill(Color.TRANSPARENT).stroke(Color.RED).build();
        // rotate
        ellypsis.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(50, 50, 45));

        // find out where is 100,100 in rotated ellypsis
        Point2D localToParent = ellypsis.localToParent(100,100);

        // draw line from that point
        Line line = new Line(localToParent.getX(), localToParent.getY(), 200, 200);
        root.getChildren().addAll(ellypsis, line);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted! I have been wandering what that method did exactly, now I know. I'm loving javafx2 more and more each day!

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of code provided in the question, I will give you a mathematical answer :)

Say you have `ellipse1` which center is `X1` and `elipse2` which center is `X2`. The transformation gives you the following

```
elipse1 --> f(elipse1) = elipse1'
```

if you want to know the transformed ellipse `ellipse1'` center coordinates (`X1'`) just do the following:

```
X1 --> f(X1) = X1`
```

So, in a nutshell, just apply the same transformation to your orginal point `X1` and you will get the transformed coordinates `X1'`. Now all what you have to do is draw a line from `X1'` to `X2`

Comment: I don't know if code would help here? Anyway,  the problem is you can't apply a tranformation to a point in javafx, and you can't ask the coordinates of a transformed point. That's the whole point of the question actually :) Seems to be a common problem in other graphical systems too if you look on SO, only option seems to be figuring out how to do the transformation manually (ie figuring out the math), and applying it again on the same point. Which I would like to avoid since javafx already did that, but doesn't expose the result.